# Swift documentation in Xcode: Multi-line description for function

Tags: swift, xcode, code-documentation

I'm using Xcode 10 with Swift 5:

There are a couple of big functions in my code that need a detailed, multi-line description. Example:

```
/**
This is paragraph 1.

This is paragraph 2.

This is paragraph 3.
*/
func Foo() {
    //Bla
}
```

What Xcode creates:

[image]

Paragraph 2 and 3 are a continuation of paragraph 1, so it's irritating to have them in a different section.

How do I keep all three paragraphes in the same section (I don't care if it's the "summary", "description",... one)?

I'm aware of the documentation documentation [here](https://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) but there's no explanation of how to do this exactly and the only example of a multi-lined comment (scroll down to: "Calling this method increments the"...) is missing exactly this line of text in the screenshot of the "documentation" popup.

**Edit:**
It's even worse if you use a list like this because the title stays behind in the "Summary" section, while the list items are pushed into the "Discussion" section:

```
/**
List Title:
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Xcode always interprets the first paragraph as a summary and everything after that  as Discussion. The Summary will also be used in context with less space. For example as a hint for the code completion.
Here is a good blog article about this that helped me: https://sarunw.com/posts/swift-documentation/